# Stylesheets and scripts bundles not working in Mono

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, css, mono, bundling-and-minification

**Background:** I am migrating an `ASP.NET` `MVC 5` application (developed in `Windows 8.1, VS2013` Community, `.NET 4.5.1`, `MySql` custom membership and role provider) project to `Monodevelop` (in `Ubuntu 14.4`, `Monodevelop`, `Mono`).

In my `~/App_Start/BundleConfig` class

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

     bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
    }
```

In my `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` view

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

In my `Web.Config`

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
```

Also

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="false"> </compilation>
```

Also `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll` is deleted from the bin directory.

**Problem:** I don't see that the bundles are getting rendered when I view source in the browser:

**The links are directing towards directories, It should show files in the directories**

```
<link href="/Content/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/bundles/modernizr"></script>
```

## This bundling is working very fine on Windows but on Ubuntu, I see only directories

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you debugging and have `<compilation debug="true" />` or     `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;`?

Comment: @rageit - I am debugging and not able to see `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` in my project. Is it something in web.config or BundleConfig? If yes how can I use it?

Comment: Do you have a `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll` in your `bin` directory? If so, try deleting it. Mono has it's own implementation it will use if this file is missing.

Comment: When optimization is turned off, is it including the individual files from the bundle?  If not, then it's probably not finding the files for the bundle.

If it does, then something is preventing the bundler from intercepting the route for the bundle's path when you have optimization turned on..

Comment: @BenjaminAnderson - are you talking about Ubuntu or Windows? On Windows there is no issue.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `MVC 5`? `MVC 5` doesn't use bundler, opting for `gulp` or `grunt` task runners instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your *BundleConfig* file add the following:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Then switch to release mode.

This should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue myself today. Mihai-Tibrea 's answer does indeed work, but it leads to unacceptable requirements for my purposes.

If always enabling bundling (BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; and/or build in release mode) is not acceptable consider the following:

In BundleConfig.cs find a line like this:

```
"~/Content/site.css"
```

Change that to

```
"~/Content/Site.css"
```

Note that in mono, the case of file names is very important, while that is not important in windows. So either your html needs to use lower-case site.css OR your bundle needs to start with a capital letter.